# Why onQueryTextChange is not triggering on double tap?

Tags: android, searchview

I have `onQueryTextChange` listener on my `SearchView.`

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String searchString) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (s.length() > 5) {
                searchView.setQuery(s.substring(0, 5), false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My goal is to limit number of characters to 5. The problem is that,

1. I am typing 5 characters.
2. After that I am typing one more character.
3. I am hitting same character again and in second hit it is not triggering the listener and it is showing the 6th character in `SearchView`

Thanks for help

Comment: try return false from `onQueryTextSubmit`

Comment: I tried it didn't change anything.

Comment: If you set s.length() > 6, what will happen? and in substring(0, 6)

Comment: I don't think it is gonna change anything. Because the problem is that it is not triggering listener on double tap. But I will try

Comment: Have you considered using a `TextView` with a `TextWatcher`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of limiting in listener, I solved it getting `EditText` in `SearchView`.

I was using this method to get `EditText` but it was returning null,

```
searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText etSearchView = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
etSearchView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
```

Instead of getting `id` of `EditText` I just passed it's actual id and it worked,

```
searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
EditText etSearchView = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_txt);
etSearchView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
```